# Dynamic Class Members

Tags: c++, templates, dynamic, c++11

I am new to C++11's variadic templates, and do not know if what I am doing wrong is a simple syntax error, or is impossible.
I would like to write something like the following:

```
template< typename... Args >
struct Test
{
    Args... args;
    Test( Args... args_ ) : args( args_... ) {
    }
};
```

Basically this class would have "pseudo dynamic members".
I have tried this with:

```
struct A {};
template< typename... Args >
A* MakeB( Args... args )
{
    struct B : public A
    {
        Args... args;
        B( Args... args_ ) : args( args_... ) {
        }
    };
    return new B;
};
```

Is it impossible, or am I just not good with variadic templates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Packs are not types, and cannot be used like types. They are a special construction only for use in templates. You cannot have a "pack member".

The typical solution is to have a tuple member:

```
#include <tuple>

template< typename... Args >
struct Test
{
    std::tuple<Args...> args_;

    Test(Args const &... args)
    : args_(args_...)
    { }
};
```

Your little maker would look like this:

```
template <typename ...Args>
Test<Args...> make_test<Args const &... args)
{
    return Test<Args>(args...);
}
```

Usage:

```
auto t = make_test(1, true, 'x');   // makes a Test<int, bool, char>
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract the data so I could use the expansion syntax to put the members into a function call effectivly i.e func( args... ); ?